# Вычисление наибольшего простого делителя решетом Эратосфена

Tags: c, алгоритм, динамические-массивы

Когда х>996 отказывается работать, помогите пожалуйста.
Собственно, код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int x, p, i, q, max, min;
scanf ("%d", &x);

int *a = (int*)malloc(abs(x)+1 * sizeof(int));

for (i=0; i<=abs(x); i++)
    a[i] = i;

a[1]=0;

for (p=2; p<=abs(x); p++){
        for (q=p*2; q<=abs(x); q+=p)
            a[q]=0;
}

max=0;

if (x>=0){
    for(i=0; i<=abs(x); i++)
        if((a[i]!=0) && (abs(x)%a[i]==0))
            if (a[i]>max)
                max=a[i];

printf("%d", max);
free(a);
}

else{

min=abs(x);

for(i=0; i<=abs(x); i++)
        if((a[i]!=0) && (abs(x)%a[i]==0))
            if (a[i]<min)
                min=a[i];

printf ("%d", -min);
free(a);
}
}
```

Comment: Используйте отладчик

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не понимаю, что значат в этой программе отрицательные значения x, но в любом случае abs(x) вычислять надо 1 раз. Ошибка случается оттого, что вы выделяете память так

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(abs(x)+1 * sizeof(int));
```

а надо

```
int *a = (int*)malloc((abs(x)+1) * sizeof(int));
```

Код можно оптимизировать - максимальный делитель определить еще при построении решета.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, p, i, q, max, min;
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    bool b=true;
    if (x<0) b=false;

    x=abs(x);
    int *a = (int*)malloc((x+1) * sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<=x; i++)
        a[i] = i;

    a[1]=0;
    max=0;
    min=0;
    for (p=2; p<=x; p++){
        if (a[p]==p)
            for (q=p*2; q<=x; q+=p)
            {
                a[q]=0;
                if(q==x) max=p;
                if(q==x&&min==0) min=p;
            }
    }

    if (b){
        printf("%d", max);
        free(a);
    }

    else{
        printf ("%d", -min);
        free(a);
    }
    _getch();
}
```